# Efficient choosing of the binary tree node childs

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I have the following code:

```
        NodePtr bestChild = (diff < 0) ? node->child1 : node->child2;
        NodePtr otherChild = (diff < 0) ? node->child2 : node->child1;
```

Is there any more efficient way to set a bestChild and otherChild variables?

**NOTE:** `diff` is `float` and comparison is quite long operation.

Also I tried the following solution:

```
        NodePtr bestChild = (diff < 0) ? node->child1 : node->child2;
        NodePtr otherChild = (bestChild == node->child2) ? node->child1 : node->child2;
```

In this case I don't make one comparison, but I'm not sure that it is a best way.

Comment: Are you sure the compare float to 0 is the bottleneck? I would expect the branching itself would have much greater affect - due to [branch misspredictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_misprediction), but I am really not an expert on this subject.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that comparison is expensive operation, but if it is possible to avoid branching, it would be great.

Comment: Is it possible to get this op faster? I mean, if I remember correctly [again not an expert] - for [IEEE754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation) the sign is just the MSB, so you can do some bit hacking there if it is indeed the bottleneck - or is it some special representation where it is not possible?

Comment: Regarding to representation, I'm not really sure, but it seems to be a good direction. Thanks.

Comment: @amit, I think 'diff' is a complex expression, I dont think he means the comparison to 0 is slow.

Comment: @MooingDuck At Cortex-A8 comparison between floats takes about 20 cycles process stall (in accordance to the profiler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

```
NodePtr bestChild, otherChild;
if (diff < 0)
{
    bestChild = node->child1;
    otherChild = node->child2;
}
else
{
    bestChild = node->child2;
    otherChild = node->child1;
}
```

or

```
NodePtr children[2] = (diff < 0) ? {node->child1, node->child2} : {node->child2, node->child1};
```

**or just leave it as it is because the compiler will probably do this for you.**